# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django' when installing django in venv

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am trying to do this:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Topic

admin.site.register(Topic)
```

however, I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

I have also tried installing django in my system but still nothing and when i check installed packages it shows django is already installed
My venv is also active so i dont know why the error is being raised?

Answer (score 1):

First create virtualenv, virtualenv env
then activate it, env/scripts/activate
later install Django, pip install Django

Create Django project, install your app name in settings.py file the run it.

If you create Djangoproject and activate virualenv later, it may fail